# Count number of transactions for first 30 days of account creation for all accounts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the number of transactions for the first 30 days from an account's creation for all accounts. The issue is not all accounts were created at the same time.

```
Example: [Acct_createdTable]
 Acct   Created_date
909099  01/02/2015
878787  02/03/2003
676767  09/03/2013
```

I can't Declare a datetime variable since it can only take one datetime.
and I can't do :

```
Select acctnumber,min,count(*)
 from transaction_table
 where transactiondate between (
    select Created_date from Acct_createdTable where Acct = 909099)
          and    (
    select Created_date from Acct_createdTable where Acct = 909099)+30
```

Since then it'll only count the number of transaction for only one acct.

What I want for my output is.

```
  Acct  First_30_days_count
909099   23 
878787   190
676767   23
```

Comment: I'm using ms SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a basic `GROUP BY` query.

```
SELECT
    ac.acctnumber,
    COUNT(td.id)
FROM Acct_createdTable ac
LEFT JOIN transactiondate td ON
    td.acct = ac.acctnumber
    AND
    td.transaction_date BETWEEN ac.create_date AND DATEADD(30, DAY, ac.create_date)
GROUP BY
    ac.acctnumber
```

This should return number of transactions within first 30 days for each account. This of course is pseudocode as you didn't state your database platform. The left join will ensure that accounts with no transactions in that period will get displayed.

Comment: Note that since you use `count(*)` accounts with no corresponding transactions will still be counted with 1. You need to do `count(td.acctnumber)` to have them at 0 count. Also, you have the parameters for dateadd in the wrong order. (As well as table and column names in some places).

Comment: You're right, screw up on my part. [Had to verify](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19484/4) to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to use `outer apply` like this:

```
select a.acct, o.First_30_days_count
from acct_createdtable a 
outer apply (
    select count(*) First_30_days_count
    from transaction_table 
    where acctnumber = a.acct 
    and transactiondate between a.created_date and dateadd(day, 30, a.created_date) 
 ) o;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follow:

```
SELECT
  acct.Acct,
  COUNT(*) AS First_30_days_count
FROM
  Acct_createdTable acct
  LEFT JOIN transaction_table trans ON acct.Acct = trans.acctnumber
                                     AND trans.transactiondate BETWEEN acct.Created_date AND DATE_ADD(acct.Created_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
  acct.Acct;
```